# Reading the remainder of this tag explanation

Tags: support, user-interface, tag-wiki-excerpt

When adding a tag to a question (e.g. on [Web Apps SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)), how can I read the remainder of the tag explanation?

[image: screenshot of tag excerpt while editing tags]

Comment: Click on the question mark icon.

Comment: In what view/platform? I see an [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) icon using Firefox instead of a question mark (that links to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag/android), including at the *"Top Questions"* page.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4SFq.png there's a view tag link then

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum it's not when hovering a tag, it's when you add tag to a question when posting a new question or editing tags of existing question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [complete tag info](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/android/info), which contains the excerpt visible in that container, as well as [more information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-wiki/info), can be accessed by clicking the question mark in the upper right corner of the container.

[image: screenshot of tag excerpt with question mark circled in green]

Comment: Hm, its a green non freehand circle. Rebel Scum. +1